# Selenium Webscraping with Looping List

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to loop through a list in which the URL to the website I am trying to scrape changes when you select what you are looking for. An example would be "buyhere.com", and when I select milk on the webpage, the url would change to "buyhere.com/milk".

So effectively, I am trying to put together a price checking webscraper through chromedriver in which I can price out a list of grocery items that I set, in this case:

```
groceries = ['milk', 'bread', 'coffee', 'cereal', 'flowers']

for k in groceries:
    url = 'https://buyhere.com/' + groceries
```

now when i put in a single item, I am able to get the information I am looking for (price, brand for instance), but when i try and loop thru, it gives me a few issues:

It will kick an error about not being able to concatenate a list to a str.
   I tried `#groceries = str(['milk', 'bread', 'coffee', 'cereal', 'flowers'])`
   I tried `#url = 'https://buyhere.com/' + str('groceries')`

Now when i am running it, it is basically spitting out:

```
 url = 'https://buyhere.com/[['milk', 'bread', 'coffee', 'cereal', 'flowers']
```

instead of pulling each individual element and looping through, it is printing my entire list in the URL.

I have thought about putting groceries[0] and leaving a k += 1 at the end, but i haven't gotten any traction there either.

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

import pandas as pd


groceries = ['milk', 'bread', 'coffee', 'cereal', 'flowers']

for k in groceries:

    url = 'https://buyhere.com/' + groceries
```

Intended result:

5 loops which pull data on each of the 5 types of groceries

```
for k in groceries:

url = 'https://buyhere.com/milk
url = 'https://buyhere.com/bread
url = 'https://buyhere.com/coffee
```

etc

Would have happy to see if anyone had any better ideas on how to solve. Thanks community!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just messed up the syntax a little, try this

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

import pandas as pd


groceries = ['milk', 'bread', 'coffee', 'cereal', 'flowers']

for k in groceries:

    url = 'https://buyhere.com/' + k
    #  do stuff with url ...
```

Comment: Unbelievable, i never would have figured that out. I sincerely appreciate the help here.

Comment: It happens, often helps to get another eye on a problem you've been staring too long at! Remember to mark it as accepted if it solved it.